How do unit tests work in test-driven development?
I've been thinking a lot about unit tests today and I got a bit puzzled as to how exactly unit tests are created during the test-driven development (TDD) process. (To be clear, a unit test for me is testing against the smallest scopes of a codebase (i.e. functions like isPrime or hasThisValue etc. So something like GetUserData is not a unit test, but rather a feature (or behavior) of the actual software)).
For me, TDD never starts with an actual unit but rather a desired feature, so e.g. Test_GetUserData. Now I write the test, it fails, I fix it, it works, and then refactor. During this refactoring step, I will create multiple units (so e.g. hasAdminStatus as a function).
So my question is: when are tests written for these refactored units? I can't now go ahead and write them after writing the actual code as that goes against TDD's philosophy. If tests are never written for these, then how exactly are unit tests (as these are clearly units) written in TDD?
Hopefully you guys understand my question, and thank you so much for reading.


how exactly unit tests are created during the test-driven development (TDD) process.

By accident.


I call them "unit tests", but they don't match the accepted definition of unit tests very well. -- Kent Beck, Test Driven Development by Example.

The "unit-ness" of the examples-we-use-to-fix-behaviors isn't actually an important constraint (so we should have used a better name, but didn't and now we are stuck with it, along with blame for all of the unnecessary confusion).
Automated checks that give coverage of multiple "units" of production code is normal.


So my question is: when are tests written for these refactored units?

There are a couple possibilities

you don't write tests specifically for these new units, but continue to fix behaviors at a larger grain
you "test-drive" new units, then replace the refactored units with the test-driven ones (using the old tests to ensure that that collaborating with the new units still produces the old behaviors).
you write tests specifically for these new units to fix their behaviors, calibrating the tests as necessary to ensure that they are actually measuring what you think they are measuring.



I can't now go ahead and write them after writing the actual code as that goes against TDD's philosophy.

You should probably let go of this idea, and be very suspicious of sources that insist that it is true.
The spelling of the original rule was

Write new code only if an automated test has failed.

This rule does not prohibit writing automated tests for existing code.
(It does mean that the "Red" task of the "Red-Green-Refactor" loop differs from its execution when the code-under-test hasn't been written yet; for instance, we may need to deliberately inject a fault in order to establish that the new test is sensitive to the variations we need it to be sensitive to.)
Also, driving design changes is not the only reason to introduce new tests.
Having "extra" tests is fine, so long as your don't sacrifice any of the important properties in your test suite (ex: that it is eye blink fast to run, stable, and so on).

Thank you for your response. I never heard that the original rule was as simple as "Write new code only if an automated test has failed". I assume that is also in Beck's TDD by Example? Going by that rule, it does make sense that tests can be written after the refactoring step. I also like the idea of "test-driving" new units - thanks for the suggestions!

Yes, it is from the Preface of TDDbE.

What you're describing is sometimes known as Outside-in TDD. This is often a good approach when, as you write, you want to implement an application feature. You start by writing high-level tests that warrant creation of just enough code to pass the test, etc. Some people also call this Behaviour-Driven Development (BDD), although this is typically conflated with the Gherkin language (Given When Then).
The opposite of Outside-in TDD is't called Inside-out TDD, as one might think, but rather Bottom-up TDD. Here, you start with something quite fine-grained and write a test for that. This is typically a function or a method on an object.
This is useful if your task is to develop a reusable library. Imagine that your task is to write a reusable library of mathematical functions, or security algorithms, or graphing procedures. In this case, it seems more appropriate to start with unit tests, since the desired delivery artefact is reusable code, rather than a full application.
Once you've shipped the first version of your library, those unit tests are now regression tests, and guard against breaking changes.
All that said, there's no universally accepted testing terminology. What I call a unit test, you may not call a unit test, or vice versa.
